# Show that if $g(x)=f(Ax)$, then $H_x(g)=A^tH_{Ax}(f)A$ , where $H$ means the hessian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ real matrix. Let $f$ and $g$ be function of class $\textsf{C}^2$ defined in the open space $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that if $g(x)=f(Ax)$, then $H_x(g)=A^tH_{Ax}(f)A$ , where $H$ means the hessian matrix.

To solve this problem I tried to think in the output of the function, like, if I have a vector $X=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and the matrix is formed by the column vectors $C_1, C_2,\dots,C_n$ so the output is $Ax=C_1x_1+C_2x_2+\cdots+C_nx_n$, but the analysis of the partial derivates got very hard to study.

Comment: Have you computed the gradient yet?

Comment: What the gradient will help in this issue?

Comment: It is related to the hessian, is it not?

Comment: I know that $H(f(x))=J(\nabla f(x))^T$, but how this will help?

Comment: But you want to show an equality? So maybe you should start by calculating the left side of the equal sign and the right side?

Comment: @MatheusDomingos Do you know what I mean? Try to calculate $J((\nabla (f(Ax)))^T)$.

Comment: I think I kind of understand, but I don't know how to handle well with this math, it appeared a double sum. I don't know how to control

Comment: With the chain rule, I don't think you need any sums! Remember, that $A$ is also a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.